# Call a single cell of LaTeX Table

Tags: latex, tabular

I would like to call a single value from a table inside a textbody.

```
% latex table generated in R 3.5.1 by xtable 1.8-3 package
% Wed Dec 12 13:56:07 2018
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
  \hline
 & Estimate & Std. Error & z value & Pr($>$$|$z$|$) \\ 
  \hline
(Intercept) & -1.819 & 0.926 & -1.964 & 0.050 \\ 
  hiveH2 & 2.418 & 0.951 & 2.542 & 0.011 \\ 
  nectar+ & 0.827 & 0.947 & 0.873 & 0.383 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:x}
\end{table}
```

I would like to be able to write something along the line:

```
The z value of Hive~2 is \call{tab:x{z value}{hiveH2}}.
```

That should compile as:

```
The z value of Hive 2 is 2.542.
```

the LaTeX table was generated with a R script (neither R markdown nor R sweave):

```
library(lme4) 
library(xtable) 

data <- matrix(c("H1","H1","H2","H2","H1","H1","H2","H2","H1","H1","H2","H2","H1","H1","H2","H2","H1","H1","H2","H2","H1","H1","H2","H2","H1","H1","H2","H2",
                       "+","+","-","-","+","+","-","-","+","+","-","-","+","+","-","-","-","-","+","+","-","-","+","+","-","-","+","+",
                       0.00000000,0.00000000,0.25000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,0.10000000,0.20000000,0.00000000,0.10000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,0.09090909,0.09090909,0.00000000,0.41666667,0.08333333,0.00000000,0.14285714,0.85714286,0.61538462,0.00000000,0.00000000,0.25000000,1.10000000),
                    nrow=28, ncol=3)


data <- as.data.frame(data)
colnames(data) <- c("hive", "nectar", "severity")

glm <-  glm(severity ~ hive + nectar, data = data, family = binomial)

summary.glm <- summary(glm)
summary.glm
print(xtable(summary.glm, type = "latex", caption.placement = getOption("xtable.caption.placement", "bottom"),
             digits = 3,
             label = "tab:x",
      table.placement = getOption("xtable.table.placement", "h")),
      file = "test.tex")
```

Comment: Can you provide the R code that produced the LaTeX `tabular`, together with data for it? Are you writing a document via R markdown?